# Can I send string data to AWS Cloudwatch and then use in Alarms?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm sending custom metrics to Cloudwatch from my EC2 servers without an issue. I'd now like to send the current version number provided by an API call (e.g."3.0.5") so that I can display it in a dashboard and force an alarm if the value isn't what I expect. I don't expect the alarm to be anything other than a straight string match. I could do this in something like Nagios but hoped I could stay within the AWS infrastructure

Any ideas?

TIA

Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think you you could do this. For that you could possibly setup [CloudWatch Filter Metric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringLogData.html) on your custom logs in CW. You would have to create such a filter that would produce numerical values which could be then used in CloudWatch Alarm.

Obviously, the alarm can't work on literal strings "3.0.5" so you would have to construct some numerical value from that. In the worst case scenario, if the filter metrics are not advanced enough to process your string log data, you could [stream the logs to lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Subscriptions.html) and then in the lambda perform more advanced processing of your logs. This way your lambda could output numerical metric values that could be then used by CW Alarms.

Comment: Thank You -  the issue with numerical version numbers is 3.11.0 is higher than 3.2.0 but 3.110 is less than 3.20 so a simple conversion didn't help. I'm dont think it'll work without strings - it's a dashboard thing rather than needing it for an alarm - I suppose I could split the version into 3 variables - major, minor, patch and display it that way.

Comment: @RichardTurner In that case you have to use lambda, as I wrote, for more complex transformations. CW alarms will not work with strings.

Comment: Thank you again. Looks like I have some reading to do!